# BlackBerry remove hourglass icon of garbage collection

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am developing a BlackBerry application that should work on OS 4.5+. I have implemented my own loading progress screen. 
On 6.0 device it works as it is supposed to do. 

[image]

But on 4.5 device it shows up with garbage collector loading hourglass. 

[image]

Is there a way to remove or hide this hourglass.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hourglass can't be removed unfortunately. My only suggestion would be to try to figure out a way to not use as much memory, such as reusing objects instead of creating new ones.